# How to find the value of $k$ for the density function defined by $f(x)=kx^2$?

Tags: statistics, probability

Suppose $x$ is a continuous random variable. The probability density function of $x$ is $f(x) = kx^2$  when $0 < x < 2$ and $f(x)= 0$ otherwise. What is the value of $k$?

More info: Does this mean I find value under the curve of $P(0 <x <2)$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If $f(x)$ is a pdf then it must be the case that $\int_0^2{f(x)dx}=1$. Use this fact to find out the value of $k$.